# VBScript Object variable not set

Tags: vbscript

I am getting the error "Object variable not set" on line 15 when I run my code. I do not get it every time. It seems to be random. I have searched, but cannot find any reason for this. I was having an issue with the variable not getting cleared all the time, so I just added line 42 Set strText = Nothing. My issue with the variable not setting properly went away, but now I have this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code is below.

```
Option Explicit
Dim i, objFSO, objFile, strText, Fields, TimeStamp, Location, MachNum, Amount, Theme, objSMFile, SMLine, p, CSVLine, objReportFile, FileName
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Do while i<>1
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Print\output.txt") Then
        '*** Clean up CR/LF and Make CSV Variable ***
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Print\output.txt", ForReading)
        If Not objFile.AtEndOfStream Then strText = objFile.ReadAll
        objFile.Close
'       WScript.Sleep 1000
        objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Print\output.txt", "C:\Print\outputCopy.txt"
        objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\Print\output.txt")
'       WScript.Sleep 3000
        strText = Replace(strText, vbCrlf, "")
        strText = Replace(strText, "   ", ";")
        ' Split by semi-colon into an array...
        Fields = Split(strText, ";")
        TimeStamp = Fields(0)
        Location = Fields(1)
        MachNum = Fields(3)
        Amount = Fields(4)
        '*** Find Machine Number in Slot Master ***
        Set objSMFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\SlotMaster.csv", ForReading)
        do while not objSMFile.AtEndOfStream
            SMLine=objSMFile.readline
            p=instr(SMLine, MachNum)
            if p>0 then CSVLine = SMLine
        Loop
        ' Split by comma into an array...
        Fields = Split(CSVLine, ",")
        Theme = Fields(7)
        '*** Create Tab Delimited Text File ***
        FileName = Year(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now) & " Jackpots.txt"
        If Not objFSO.FileExists("C:\Print\" & FileName) Then
            Set objReportFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Print\" &FileName)
            objReportFile.Close
        End If
        Set objReportFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Print\" & FileName, ForAppending)
        objReportFile.Write TimeStamp & vbTab & Location & vbTab & Amount & vbTab & Theme & vbCrLf
        objReportFile.Close
        Set strText = Nothing
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER

`strText` is not an object. Its there to handle a string.

You should thus reinit it with:

```
strText= ""
```

---

LONG ANSWER

When you do

```
Set strText = Nothing
```

1. You *implicitly* declare `strText` as an *object*, and thus it is not a *string* anymore. Trying to assign it a value `""` (blank string) is therefore not  allowed.
2. You decrement it's reference counter, which renders the object not addressable anymore and candidate for the garbage collector. So the next time `Replace()` or `.ReadAll` would be executed on it, it would fail because it just does not exists anymore. And even if it existed it would fail because it is not a *string* anymore, as stated previously.

Comment: Now I am getting a random "Subscript out of range: '[number: 0]" on line 17.